# Does "ChartFX" support asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, chartfx

Today started doing some research for good plugins for asp.net mvc and found ChartFX sounds like it supports .net but doesn't support asp.net mvc. Is it true? Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Chart FX does support ASP.NET MVC. Here is sample showing how-to: <http://support.softwarefx.com/Chart_FX_8/article/2601324>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChartFX has not been designed for web applications but you could integrate it into ASP MVC by using silverlight (http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxNetProducts/ChartFX/silverlight/) I recommend you to use some client-side javascript based data visualization / charting tool:

http://processingjs.org/ (Open source)

http://www.highcharts.com/ (Private)

http://www.jqplot.com/ (Open source)

Hope it helps :)